# How do I get rid of all the unnecessary padding and margins in c3.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, c3.js

I want to get rid of all the spacing basically, i.e the extra spaces for axes and legends and want the c3 lines to attach/fit to the div element.

I tried to use svg viewBox attribute for it to scale to fit the div, but it was not giving me the desired result

Comment: Mind explaining which one exactly? Some minimal effort is required from your side. Maybe consider a [repro].

Comment: @kissu here is the jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/x2fw8s3h/3/, I need the chart to fit the div#chart

Comment: If you inspect the DOM, you can see that there is an SVG with coordinates there. Meaning that you will need to change those coordinates for it to take the whole container. Quick to say that the library either does this by itself or you won't have a lot of control overall.